# How to create logic hook in SuiteCRM Leads to calculate and display Days Since Last Activity for a given record

Tags: logic, hook, sugarcrm, suitecrm

This would be displayed in a new field Days Since Last Activity and based on Today minus Date Modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on whatever hook u want

```
<?php

    if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class logic_hooks_class
    {
        function after_retrieve_method($bean, $event, $arguments)
        {
                $date_modified = $bean->date_modified;
                $datetime1 = new DateTime();
                $datetime2 = new DateTime($date_modified);
                $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
                $elapsed = $interval->format('%a');
                $bean->days_since_last_activity_c = $elapsed;
        }
    }

?>
```